# unicode() for all characters of a query

Tags: unicode, sqlite

The `unicode()` function in SQLite just accepts one parameter; if I execute this query:

```
select unicode(text) from table
```

and suppose the `table` has just 1 row which is `abc`; then the result would be: `97` which is the numeric unicode code for just `a` character; what if I want to get the numeric unicode code for all characters in the result of the query? Is such a thing possible within SQLite?

(I know that I can get the numerical codes out of SQLite within the environment of a programming language; I'm just curious if such a thing is possible with a SQL command within SQLite or not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not really have looping constructs; doing this in the programming language would be much easier.

In SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you could use a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
all_chars(id, u, rest) AS (
    SELECT id, unicode(text), substr(text, 2)
    FROM MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, unicode(rest), substr(rest, 2)
    FROM all_chars
    WHERE rest <> ''),
unicodes(id, list) AS (
    SELECT id, group_concat(u)
    FROM all_chars
    GROUP BY id)
SELECT * FROM unicodes
```

The ID is required to merge the values of a single source row back together; doing this for a single, specific row in `MyTable` would be easier.